# Magento 2.3.0 from Backend Product Edit not working

Tags: product, magento2.3.0

I have Magento 2.3.0. I have an issue while updating the product from backend.
It's giving me an error message "Invalid input DateTime format of value 'Invalid date' ".

I am not finding any solution to why this thing happen.

[image]

If anyone has a solution please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make sure that your **date locale** on your admin user is set to **`English (US)`** - some other locales have issues validating the date format.

You can achieve this under **`System > Permissions > All Users > (your username) > User Info > Interface Locale`**.

Comment: No correct locale is assigned.